# Tracking user_pseudo_id for the same user across separate GA4 properties

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

I am tracking different parts of my app using separate ga4 properties. does user_pseudo_id remain consistent across these? or does it change from one property to the other for the same user.

If it is not consistent, how do I address this problem? Please note, I would be analyzing the data on bigquery and firebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO, the User_pseudo_id(CID) is unique to each user across different GA4 properties.
One solution is setting the cross-domain tracking option in GA4. Cross-domain tracking allows you to share the CID across multiple properties.

consider that cross-domain tracking is not a perfect solution. There may be some cases where the CID does not stay the same across different properties.